# Python Recursion without While loop and find remainder of x/y without using %operators?

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, operators

Not sure what went wrong, it's not giving output, and I'm thinking of putting "remainder(x-y, y)" in the statement, but still not working.

```
def remainder(x, y):
  if x == y:
    return 0
  elif x>y:
    x = x-y
    if x<y:
      return x

x=int(input("x: "))
y=int(input("y: "))
print (f'Remainder: {remainder(x, y)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function to perform recursion

```
def remainder(x, y):
  if y==0: # check to avoid infinite loops
    return float("Nan")
  if x>=y:
    return remainder(x-y, y)
  else: # base case
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

'Recursion', by definition, means that your function *calls itself* at some point. So far, yours doesn't. Consider the flow through your function for a set of inputs - say, `x=22` and `y=7`, and *walk through each statement* to see what it's doing. This usually helps to debug.

When designing a recursive function, it's usually easiest to start with *what you're doing to recur* (in this case, subtracting `y` from `x`). Then, ask *what would be the base case* - what are the circumstances that make it impossible to recur further? In this case, if subtracting `y` from `x` would put the result below zero. In other words, if `y` is greater than `x`. Then, the rest of the function is just setting up for calling itself, and calling itself.

In this case, what you'd actually want to do to implement modulo via recursion is more simple:

```
def remainder(x, y):
  # base case
  if y > x:
    return x 
  # recursive case
  return remainder(x-y, y)
```

Each iteration of the function subtracts another `y` from `x`, until `y` is larger than `x`, at which point whatever `x` is is returned as the remainder.

Note that this will not work for negative numbers, for what should be obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this answer you need no recursion.

```
def remainder(x,y):
    ans = x/y
    rem = y * (ans-int(ans))
    return round(rem)

remainder(132,7)
```

will give you
`6`

Comment: Why bother with rounding? Just use the integer division operator `//`.

Comment: we need remainder. this will give you a quotient